# Redis connection failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, redis

I'm building an application which uses Node, redis and mongo. I finished the development, and I want to containerize it with docker.

Here's my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:13.8.0-alpine3.11
RUN npm install -g pm2
WORKDIR /user/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
```

And here my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    container_name: scrapr-redis
    image: 'redis:6.0-rc1-alpine'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  mongo-db:
    container_name: scrapr-mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    command: --auth
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=db
  app:
    container_name: scrapr-node
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
      - '3001:3001'
    links:
      - mongo-db
    depends_on:
      - redis-server
    environment:
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PWD=pass
      - DB_NAME=db
      - REDIS_HOST=redis-server
    command: 'node index.mjs'
```

I can start the service successfully, but when node starts, it generates the following error:

> Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

When I do `docker ps -a`, I can see that all containers are running:

[image]

Why can't it connect with redis? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` does not look right to me at all. Let me get the quick checks out of the way first, are you sure you are using the REDIS_HOST env variable in the node app correctly? I would add some console logging to your node app to echo out the env variables to check what they are.

Secondly try attach to the running scrapr-node with `docker container exec -it  scrapr-node sh` or /bin/bash if sh does not work.

Then run `nslookup scrapr-redis` from the shell, this will give you the ip address of the redis container. if `ping scraper-redis` returns then you know its an issue with your node app not the docker network.

you can also exec into the redis node and run `hostname -I` which should show the same ip address as you saw from the other container.

This should help you to debug the issue.

EDIT:

Ensure that you are correctly getting the value from your environment into your node app using `process.env.REDIS_HOST` and then correctly using that value when connecting to redis something like:

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
  port: 6379
});
```

I would not try and force 127.0.0.1 on the docker network (if that is even possible) it is reserved as the loopback address.

Comment: you're right. `nslookup scrapr-redis` return 127.0.0.11:53. Is it possible to change the container host to 127.0.0.1 for redis? I did pretty much search but can't find a correct  way to do this. For instance, I found this [article](https://books.google.mg/books?id=2f50DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA122&lpg=PA122&dq=redis+run+127.0.0.11+instead+of+127.0.0.1&source=bl&ots=R6negYLYW3&sig=ACfU3U3lou3EGp88gUTOwnMaBC4O6Hul-g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq4obrh__nAhXSZxUIHZ3cBtMQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=redis%20run%20127.0.0.11%20instead%20of%20127.0.0.1&f=false)

Comment: I would say you are 99% there with regards to running this in docker. please see my edit to the answer. Is there a specific reason for wanting 127.0.0.1 ???

Comment: The article you reference does not set the ip of the redis server to 127.0.0.1 it is showing how you can have multiple redis containers running and how you can alias a different name into a running container. This is quite complex when you are learning and would not worry about trying to do that sort of thing. Rather for your immediate issue concentrate on using the correct variable / ip address when creating the redis client in the node app